# Format a new SSD to exFAT on a notebook with a single hdd slot and without using usb-sata adapter

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I bought a Kingston SSD A400 120GB for a 1st generation macbook.

I replaced the HDD with the SSD, and booted the computer (pen drive plugged with snow leopard). I was about to install the OS but when I was asked where to install it, the list was empty (SSD not showing). So I opened the terminal and wrote "diskutil list", but in the list the SSD was not showing.

I thought it has to do with partitions, since the SSD was new maybe it had no partitions. So I took my windows notebook and replaced the SSD with the new one, then I booted with a installation pen drive plugged in, and I created a partition (without installing windows), which I guess is NTFS.

Then I put the SSD back on the mac, but still it is not showing.

I read that only FAT32 and exFAT are fully compatible both with mac os and windows os, so I would like to format the SSD with exFAT file system. Problem is that my windows notebook has a single hdd slot and I don't have a usb-sata adapter to connect the SSD to USB port and format it from windows.

So if I install windows 10 on the new SSD, is then a way to format it with exFAT?

Comment: Windows cannot be installed on an exFAT partition.

Comment: If I install windows on a NTFS partition, can I then format it with exFAT in some ways?

Comment: No, What you describe is not possible.  The Windows partition cannot be exFAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [create a Linux LiveUSB with persistence](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/), install `gparted` and `part` on it (if using a Debian or Debian derived Linux, such as Mint or Ubuntu, with `sudo apt-get install part gparted` ) as well as downloading and installing `util-linux-ng` from ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux-ng/ ; boot with it in the USB port w/ the SSD installed, and run `gparted` to completely erase the prior partition table and create a new GPT partition table. Then, run `mkfs.exfat /dev/sda1` to make an exFAT partition.

Comment: to install `part` should I use `sudo apt-get install part` or something else?

Comment: Thank you very much for updating the answer, however i think the linux liveusb with persistence is not working. I installed ubuntu 18.04 on external hard drive following step by step the guide your guide (How to Create a Live Ubuntu USB Drive With Persistent Storage) however i tried creating a folder on the desktop and then I restarted, but then the folder was not there anymore.

Comment: Not certain that Linux is installed on an external HDD the same as on a flashdrive.

Comment: Ok, but is it really necessary to have a linux live with persistence to erase and create a partition on the SSD? Is it not enough to install the SSD, plug the live linux usb, boot the computer, install gparted, part and util-linux-ng, then run gparted and make an exFAT partition?

Answer (score 0):

You can create two partitions and install Windows on one of them, necessarily one NTFS partition, the other you can format as exFAT.

Are you remembering to format your SSD with GPT?

Comment: How that is accomplished is well documented.